# Django Formset Redirect with pk/id

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass in the parent id of a formset into a view, but it doesn't seem to work for me for some reason.  I do this in other apps without issue but this particular one returns "None" as a pk.  The only difference being my formset model doesn't usually contain a foreignkey relationship.  If I render the parent by itself, I can pass the pk just fine.  Please help :)

> Exception Value:     Reverse for 'company-detail' with keyword
>   arguments '{'pk': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['customers/(?P[0-9a-z-]+)/detail/$']

'''
urls.py
'''

```
   url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9a-z-]+)/detail/$', CompanyDetailView.as_view(),
       name='company-detail'),
```

'''
forms.py
'''

```
class CompanyCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyModel
        fields = [
            'name',
            'website',
            'rate',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': ''}),
            'website': forms.URLInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': ''}),
            'rate': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': ''}),
        }


SitesFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    CompanyModel,
    SiteModel,
    fields=('street1',
            'street2',
            'city',
            'state',
            'zipcode',
            'country',
            'phone',
            'distance',
           ),
    widgets={
            'street1': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'street2': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'state': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'zipcode': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'country': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
            'distance': forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control'
            })
    },
    extra=1
)
```

'''
views.py
'''

```
def companycreateview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        companyform = CompanyCreateForm(request.POST)
        if companyform.is_valid():
            company = companyform.save(commit=False)
            sitesform = SitesFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=company)
            if sitesform.is_valid():
                company.save()
                sitesform.save()
        return redirect('customers:company-detail', pk=company.pk)
    else:
        companyform = CompanyCreateForm()
        sitesform = SitesFormSet()
    context = {
        'company': companyform,
        'sites': sitesform,
        }
    return render(request, 'customers/new-company.html', context)

class CompanyDetailView(DetailView):
    model = CompanyModel
    context_object_name = 'company'
    template_name = 'customers/company-detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(CompanyDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['sites'] = SiteModel.objects.filter(company=self.get_object())
            context['contacts'] = ContactModel.objects.filter(site__company=self.get_object())
            context['reports'] = ServiceReportModel.objects.filter(site__company=self.get_object())
            return context
```

'''
new-company.html.html
'''

```
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 form-col-md form-col-right-just {% if report.equipment.errors %}bg-danger{% endif %}">
                <label for="{{ company.name.id_for_label }}"><Strong>Company Name</Strong></label></a>
                {{ company.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 form-col-md form-col-right-just {% if report.equipment.errors %}bg-danger{% endif %}">
                <label for="{{ company.website.id_for_label }}"><Strong>Website</Strong></label></a>
                {{ company.website }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 form-col-md form-col-right-just {% if report.equipment.errors %}bg-danger{% endif %}">
                <label for="{{ company.rate.id_for_label }}"><Strong>Hourly Rate</Strong></label></a>
                {{ company.rate }}
            </div>
        </div>

        {{ sites.management_form }}
        {{ sites.non_form_errors }}

        {% for child_form in sites %}
            {{ child_form.sites_id.as_hidden }}
            {{ child_form.company.as_hidden }}

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 form-col-md">
                    <label for="{{ child_form.id_for_label }}"><Strong>{{ child_form.label }}</Strong></label>
                    {{ child_form }}
                    {% if child_form.errors %}
                        {% for error in child_form.errors %}
                            {{ error|escape }}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12 form-col-md form-col-left-just">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-detail"><Strong>Submit</Strong></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Before `return redirect('customers:company-detail', pk=company.pk)`, can you check if pk is not None?

Comment: @dvnguyen of course, but that's not a solution :)

Comment: @Jaberwocky, please post your `urlpatterns` codes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a small change to your url patterns. The error shows that the following pattern found no matches:

```
['customers/(?P[0-9a-z-]+)/detail/$']
```

Try adding `<pk>` directly after `?P`:

```
customers/(?P<pk>[0-9a-z-]+)/detail/$
```

Comment: As I said, if I render the parent by itself, it works fine.  That means, that my url pattern is already established.  But to your point, I have added my urlpattern for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In your `urls.py`:
I think you missed `pk` in urlpatterns.

```
url('customers/(?P<pk>[0-9a-z-]+)/detail/$',.......)
```

In you `views.py`:

As your coding indentation if somehow `sitesform` is invalid then it'll try to redirect. But `company` is not saved yet into database. So `pk` is `None`. The code should be like below:

```
if companyform.is_valid():
    company = companyform.save(commit=False)
    sitesform = SitesFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=company)
    if sitesform.is_valid():
        company.save()
        sitesform.save()
        return redirect('customers:company-detail', pk=company.pk)
```

Comment: As I said, if I render the parent by itself, it works fine.  That means, that my url pattern is already established.  But to your point, I have added my urlpattern for clarification.

Comment: Did you check the second portion of my answer ?

Comment: Yes.  You're right I missed a tab.  That still didn't fix my problem though.  :(